# Captar evento de actualización, cambio o cierre de página

Tags: php, javascript

Hola necesito saber si el usuario salió de la página o actualizó, para poder borrar el contenido que con anterioridad ingresó en un anterior formulario.

Para ello utilizo el siguiente código para mostrar el mensaje:

```
print "<script language='JavaScript'>
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return 'Ha intentado salir de esta pagina. Si ha realizado algun cambio en los campos sin hacer clic en el boton Guardar, los cambios se perderan. Seguro que desea salir de esta pagina? ';
  }
</script>"
```

El problema es que ahora quiero obtener el evento de que si clikeo en salir o no . Estoy trabajando en **PHP** y necesito enviar esa variable, ya sea **true** o **false** para seguir con el proceso.

Gracias!

Comment: O sea, ¿tienes algún elemento donde se hace click para salir y deseas saber cuando se presione en ese elemento? Deberías mostrar el HTML que contiene ese elemento. Y, ten en cuenta que un usuario puede salir cerrando la pestaña o el navegador...

Comment: Hola , No, tan solo quiero que cuando el usuario intente salir de la página o cerrar el navegador muestre el mensaje de confirmación  (el código que escribí anteriormente hace eso ),pero no sé cómo obtener si el usuario hizo click en salir o no,  ese es mi problema saber si el usuario dió click en salir